# Refresh button for an iframe jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have a problem. I have a page in which i have inside an iframe. In the parent page (not in the iframe),  i want to build the browser buttons back, fw, refresh and home page.
The back, fw, home page buttons are almost ok. The refresh button doesnt work.
The code is below:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('my_frame').location.reload();">
```

I also have to tell that my url is not changing i mean i have used post method and the url is always the same. 
Any answers of jquery or javascript???

Thanks in advence, i m really desperate

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" onClick="parent.document.getElementById('skata').location.reload();">

Comment: Just add 4 spaces before any code and don't paste the code in an answer (as you did before) OR comment!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's cover some ground rules first

1. To get access to a frame's `window` object, go through the `frames` collection.
2. Give your frame a `name`
3. If parts of your UI don't work without javascript enabled, then don't put them in the markup - add them with javascript
4. Don't use anchor elements for controls that aren't hyperlinks

In practice:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #toolbar button {
      cursor: pointer;  
    }
  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">  

  $(function()
  {
    var $iframe  = $( '#my_frame' );
    var $toolbar = $( '<div/>' ).attr( 'id', 'toolbar' );
    var frame    = self.frames['my_frame'];

    $toolbar.append(
      $('<button/>')
      .text( 'Home' )
      .click( function( event )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        frame.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
      } )
    );

    $toolbar.append(
      $('<button/>')
      .text( 'Back' )
      .click( function( event )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.back();
      } )
    );

    $toolbar.append(
      $('<button/>')
      .text( 'Forward' )
      .click( function( event )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        frame.history.forward();
      } )
    );

    $toolbar.append(
      $('<button/>')
      .text( 'Refresh' )
      .click( function( event )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        frame.location.reload();
      } )
    );

    $toolbar.insertBefore( $iframe );

  } );

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <iframe id="my_frame" name="my_frame" width="400" height="300" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the code that you wrote, but i think that the iframe doesnt reloads again. Your code also has the same problem as mine. When i press the back button, i want only to go back to the iframe. So when the history of the iframe ends, it goes back of the main page. I googled it and i found a hash function stg like that. It doesnt work on me because of the not url changing

Comment: That's not possible.  The `history` object has a `length` property, but there's no way to determine where in the history you currently are, which would be required information to perform such a task.  And the refresh *does* work.

Comment: Yes thank you it works. I had done a mistake. But i didnt understand stg about the history you are writting. Sorry my english is pure. I mean that i dont want the back button to goes back when the history of the iframe ends.

Comment: When the history of the frame "ends" - the back button does nothing.  But you can't determine that you're at the end of the history.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
http://www.byronsorrells.com/web-development/reloading-an-iframe-with-jquery/

```
$(".reloadAds").click(function() {
        jQuery.each($("iframe"), function() {
            $(this).attr({
                src: $(this).attr("src")
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that when i press the refresh button, because of the reason that the url doesnt change it loads again the src which is the home page of the site of the iframe...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('my_frame').location.reload();">
```

You don't need a `onclick` if you already have a `href` with no other target.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```